# Raspberry pi voice encryption over GSM

Tags: audio, i2c, gsm, i2s

I'm not expert in RPI, so I need help to make a voice encryption model for calls over GSM. I have lot of questions.

So I want to use raspberry pi 3 and Sim900l for GSM.

I will need a microphone for voice input and speaker for voice output so when the person talk the voice goes through the microphone to be processed in the rpi then the voice go to the gsm sim900l to send the voice.

the changement should happens when the rpi process the audio before sending it to the rpi and when it receives the voice from the sim900l to send it to the speaker.

My questions:

1. It is possible to do this project with rpi?
2. Do we can modify sound before sending it to the sim900l?
3. Do we need I2S circuit to make this project?

Comment: Yes it should be possible. You should be able to do some of it, I am not sure about real time sound encryption, but take a look at this project: https://hackaday.io/project/19035-zerophone-a-raspberry-pi-smartphone/ - however I can't help you with audio encryption

Comment: It's far easier to encrypt the data stream and do VoIP. You can have a look at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14623/analogue-encryption-algorithms which gives some hints. All told, I woudn't expect homemade crypto to be secure. Use signal from Open Whisper systems.